# Proving monotonicity of a equation.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $f : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and let $x_1,x_2$ be two points in $(a,b).$ Then $f'$ assumes all real values between $f'(x_1)$ and $f'(x_2).$
>
> Hint: Consider $x_1 < x_2$ and a singular value $c$ between $f'(x_1)$ and $f'(x_2),$ set $g(x) = f(x) - cx,$ show that $g(x)$ is not monotonic.

My work:

WLOG let $x_1 < x_2$ and $f'(x_1) < c < f'(x_2).$ Setting $g(x) = f(x) - cx.$ Then $g'(x) = f'(x) - c$ and thus $g'(x_1) = f'(x_1) - c < 0$ and $g'(x_2) = f'(x_2) - c > 0$ from the inequalities. So $\implies g'(x_1)g'(x_2) < 0.$

My problem:

How do I proceed to show that $g(x)$ is not monotonic ? Am I overlooking something ?

P.S. **I do NOT want a full solution**, I want a hint to solve it myself.

Comment: What's the definition of monotone function? You would start writing the definition.

Comment: @Alex Definition: A monotonic function is a function which either keeps increasing or decreasing. Since I let $x_1 < x_2$ so $g$ would be monotonic if $g(x_1) < g(x_2).$ Since $g'(x_1) < 0$ and $g'(x_2) > 0,$ it would be that $g$ is decreasing in the first case and increasing in the second (viz. for $x_1$ and $x_2$). Hence $g$ must not be monotonic.
\\
Is this correct ?

Comment: You have shown that $g$ is not monotonic but you still have to use that to deduce that there is a point $p$ such that $g'(p)=0$. That will give that $f'(p)=c$ which is what you want to prove. We can't use the intermediate value theorem because we don't know that $g'$ is continuous.